# Choppy/crappy animation in IE using jquery opacity + animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I realize there are multiple questions about the animation of opacity - so before anyone goes all RTFM on me - I checked, and I couldn't find one with my specific problem :)

Consider the following code:

```
$("#contentTabs li").live({
     mouseenter: function () {
          $(this).find("span.tabTitle").stop(true, true).animate({
             marginTop: "-25px"
          }, 250);
     },
     mouseleave: function () {
          $(this).find("span.tabTitle").stop(true, true).animate({
             marginTop: "-10px"
          }, 500);
     }
});
```

This works quick and fast in both IE and other browsers - (if you're wondering, all it does is sliding caption at the bottom of a picture).

Now, I threw this in:

```
 $("#contentTabs li span.tabTitle").css({ opacity: 0.70 });
 $("#contentTabs li span.tabTitleText").css({ opacity: 1 });
```

Just before the live-declaration. And it's still quick and fast in other browsers but IE.

Why would this opacity change so much? And is there anything to be helped, besides telling IE browsers not to do the fading?

**EDIT:**

Sorry - basic question-skills are failing me, IE version tested: 8

Comment: what specific version of IE are you using?

Comment: Opacity in IE8 and lower is very flaky at the best of times, and trying to animate it is likely to make things even worse. There's not much you can do about it; it's a bad browser. Best option: find an alternative way to achieve what you want, at least in IE8 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

Opacity isn't a trivial thing to do for computers, because it requires quite a bit of calculation, and the JavaScript and rendering engines of IE 8 are no where nearly as optimized as those of current browsers.

Basically there is nothing you can do there, other than avoid unnecessary special effects in IE <9.

Comment: I wonder how the performance would be if a transparent png overlay were used instead of css opacity?

Comment: Considering that IE 6 doesn't support alpha-transparency on PNGs, and when it does, it uses the same "filter technology" as for opacity, I don't think it would help much. But it may be worth a try.

Comment: I just think it's odd - because I'm not actually animating the transparency - that's static, but I'm moving the transparent element around. And I don't plan on offering support for anything below ie 7 anyway :)